# my thread is not working well it gives all result, together at last not one by one & GUI is got hanged during thread run?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I want to search files by name in a particular location as selected by the user. I want that as soon as I got the file. It must be put in QTreeWidget parallely and showing a QMovie(":/images/img_searching.gif") while searching is in progress until user did not stop searching.

**ThreadSearch.h**

```
#ifndef QTHREADSEARCH_H
#define QTHREADSEARCH_H
#include <QThread>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QWaitCondition>
#include <QFileInfoList>

class QThreadSearchFileName : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QThreadSearchFileName(QObject *parent = 0);
   ~QThreadSearchFileName();
    void run();
    void getAllfiles(QStringList, QDir);

signals:
    void fileInfoList(QFileInfo);

private:
    QMutex m_Mutex;
    QWaitCondition m_WaitCondition;


};
#endif
```

**ThreadSearch.cpp**

```
#include "ThreadSearch.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QThread>



QThreadSearchFileName::QThreadSearchFileName(QObject *parent):QThread(parent)
{

}

QThreadSearchFileName::~QThreadSearchFileName()
{
    m_WaitCondition.wakeOne();
    wait();
}

void QThreadSearchFileName::run()
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&m_Mutex); 

}

void QThreadSearchFileName::getAllfiles(QStringList targetStrList, QDir currentdir)
{
    for(long int i1=0; i1<targetStrList.size(); i1++) 
    {
        QString targetStr;
        targetStr = targetStrList[i1];
        QDirIterator it(currentdir, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
        while (it.hasNext()) 
        {
            QString filename = it.next();
            QFileInfo file(filename);

            if (file.isDir()) 
            { // Check if it's a dir
                continue;
            }

            if (file.fileName().contains(targetStr, Qt::CaseInsensitive)) 
            {
                emit fileInfoList(file);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDirIterator>

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
     {
       QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
       QThreadSearchFileName *m_pSearchFileNameThread = new QThreadSearchFileName;
        for(int i=0; i<userSelectedpathList.size(); i++)
         {
           QDir dir(userSelectedpathList[i]);
           m_pSearchFileNameThread ->getAllfiles(stringListToBeSearch, dir);
           connect(m_pSearchFileNameThread,SIGNAL(fileInfoList(QFileInfo)),this,SLOT(searchFileNameResult(QFileInfo)));
          }   

       return a.exec();
      }


 void main::searchFileNameResult(QFileInfo file1)   //Now Making SearchFile Name Tree
  {
   QTreeWidgetItem *SearchTreeItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(m_psearchProgresswdgt->finalSearchList_treeWidget);
   SearchTreeItem->setCheckState(0,Qt::Unchecked);
   SearchTreeItem->setText(1,file1.baseName());
  }
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html)? What did you try?

Comment: The [`QThread` documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details) has a great example of a worker object that should suit your needs perfectly.

Comment: I found this article very helpfull the first time I had to do a QThread https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

Answer (score 2):

It is good practice to separate such operations out from GUI object. What is more I would suggest higher-level async mechanism provided by QObject:

- Make some class which could handle searching, for example
  **SearchingClass**:

  ```
  class SearchingClass : public QObject {
      Q_OBJECT
  public:
      void setSomeSearchParametersOrSomething(QObject* something);
  public slots:
      void search();
  signals:
      void found(QObject* objectThatHasBeenFound);
  }
  ```
- Create instance of this class and move it into another thread:

  ```
  auto searchingObject = new SearchingClass();
  searchingObject->setSomeSearchParametersOrSomething(...);
  auto thread = new QThread();
  searchingObject->moveToThread(thread);
  connect(this, SIGNAL(startSearchingSignal()), searchingObject, SLOT(search()));
  connect(searchingObject, SIGNAL(found(QObject*)), this, SLOT(someHandleFoundSlot(QObject*)));
  emit startSearchingSignal();
  ```
- Make sure that *found* signal is being emitted every time that searching algorithm finds some result.
- Ofc you must implement *someHandleFoundSlot* and declarate *startSearchingSignal* signal in GUI class.

I assume that you barely know Qt framework, so you should read about [signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) as well as [Qt meta-object system](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html) to fully understand whole code.

**EDIT:**
I see that you have edited your question. Your problem has several solution, I will describe you, what you did wrong comparably to what I had posted here.

1. Do not extend `QThread`. Extend `QObject` instead. It makes you can call `moveToThread` method. Crete an instance of `QThread` and pass it to this method. It causes later execution of slots to be performed in the thread you passed.
2. Do not make identical connections in loop until you want it to be executed more than once.
3. Make method `getAllfiles` (or `search` in my example) to be *slot* and do not call it manually. When you call method manually, it will **always** be performed in the same thread. Just connect it to some *signal*, and *emit* that *signal*.
   [Just like you emit signal when you find matching file – the result is being handled in the slots objects thread.]
4. It's your decision, if you want to have thread for every single `userSelectedpathList` element. I would advice you to do it in one working thread (it's disc operations, I think it wouldn't be faster) and iterate that list inside `getAllfiles` method.

Comment: You can’t pass QObjects by values, and those input and output arguments shouldn’t be QObjects at all.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld you are right. I wrote this as pseudo-code and I didn't even compile it. It is clear that arguments would be completely different type. But I've changed it to pointers just to make pseudo-code more like real code ;)

Comment: Thanks for your support its working partialy not exactly what I want.

Comment: @rohit_chauhan So explain what you want more briefly if you want. I gave most generic solution for your problem ofc, without implementation of searching algorithm.

Comment: I want to search files by name in a particular location as selected by the user. I want that as soon as I got the file. It must be put in `QTreeWidget` parallely and showing a `QMovie(":/images/img_searching.gif")` while searching is in progress until user did not stop searching.

Comment: My thread is give all searching result together not one by one.

Comment: So you can call `emit found(foundFileName)` as soon as you find it and this doesn't cause returning from the function (you can `emit` multiple times). The algorithm is still running and `someHandleFoundSlot` can add found file to `QTreeWidget` in the same time in main thread or any thread you want.

Comment: searchFileNameResult is called all time, till loop terminate as connect in loop.

Comment: @rohit_chauhan: You really should read some instructions, how to ask and answer questions here. My answer now doesn't look like it matches your question. And people wouldn't "google up" this thread when they want to know something about Qt's threads. You should have just add some additional content to previous question, just like I did with my answer :)

Comment: Sorry I did not know instructions well. Actually I am new here. But I'll surely remember it for next.

Answer (score 0):

Previously I gave you generic answer about "how to do async work in Qt". Here's a simple implementation for your use case (I hope you will learn something).

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QDirIterator>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPushButton>
#include "filesearchingclass.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0){
        setCentralWidget(&pushButton);
        connect (&pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(main()));   //invoke this->main() in event loop when button is pressed
        qRegisterMetaType<QFileInfo>("QFileInfo");
        searchingThread.start();    //thread must be started
    }

    ~MainWindow(){
        searchingThread.quit();
        searchingThread.wait();
    }

public slots:
    void main() {

        //EXAMPLE PARAMETERS:
        QStringList pathList;
        pathList.append("/home");
        pathList.append("/var/log");

        QStringList stringListToBeSearch;
        stringListToBeSearch.append(".jpg");
        stringListToBeSearch.append(".log");
        //-------------------

        auto fileSearchingObject = new FileSearchingClass();    //dynamic as you can't destroy object when it is out of scope
        fileSearchingObject->moveToThread(&searchingThread);    //important!!!
        fileSearchingObject->setTargetStrList(stringListToBeSearch);
        fileSearchingObject->setPaths(pathList);

        connect(this,SIGNAL(startSearching()),fileSearchingObject,SLOT(search()));  //do not call fileSearchingObject->search() manually
        connect(fileSearchingObject,SIGNAL(foundFile(QFileInfo)),this,SLOT(searchFileNameResult(QFileInfo)));   //handle every result in event loop
        connect(fileSearchingObject, SIGNAL(searchFinished()), fileSearchingObject, SLOT(deleteLater()));   //no need to wory about deleting fileSearchingObject now

        emit startSearching();  //like calling fileSearchingObject->search() but in another thread (because of connection)

    }

signals:
    void startSearching();

public slots:
    void searchFileNameResult(QFileInfo fileInfo) {
        //do something
        qDebug() << "---FOUND---" << fileInfo.absoluteFilePath() << "\n";
    }

private:
    QThread searchingThread;
    QPushButton pushButton;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**filesearchingclass.h**

```
#ifndef FILESEARCHINGCLASS_H
#define FILESEARCHINGCLASS_H

#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QDirIterator>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>

class FileSearchingClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ~FileSearchingClass(){}

    void setPaths (const QStringList &paths) {
        userSelectedPathList = paths;
    }

    void setTargetStrList(const QStringList &value) {
        targetStrList = value;
    }

public slots:
    void search() {
        for(int i=0; i<userSelectedPathList.size(); i++) {
            QDir currentDir(userSelectedPathList[i]);
            for(long int i1=0; i1<targetStrList.size(); i1++)
            {
                QString targetStr;
                targetStr = targetStrList[i1];
                QDirIterator it(currentDir, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
                while (it.hasNext())
                {
                    QString filename = it.next();
                    QFileInfo file(filename);

                    if (file.isDir())
                    { // Check if it's a dir
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (file.fileName().contains(targetStr, Qt::CaseInsensitive))
                    {
                        emit foundFile(file);   //calling MainWindow::searchFileNameResult directly is possible, but bad idea. This thread is only focused in searching, not modifing widgets in GUI.

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        emit searchFinished();  //it's always good to know when job is done.
    }

signals:
    void foundFile(QFileInfo);
    void searchFinished();

private:
    QStringList userSelectedPathList;
    QStringList targetStrList;
};

#endif // FILESEARCHINGCLASS_H
```

Comment: in `search()` function unable to catch `emit foundFile(file);`  `SIGNAL` . how do i catch this signal to show in my GUI. If I am getting this signal continually my  work is done.

Comment: Because I have to add,  searching file (if found) to my tree one by one without hanging the GUI.

Comment: That's `searchFileNameResult`'s responsibility. Insert GUI's stuff there. The signal is already connected to the slot here: `connect(fileSearchingObject,SIGNAL(foundFile(QFileInfo)),this,SLOT(searchFileNameResult(QFileInfo)));`

Comment: You really should read articles I linked you in the first answer.